# Separate definition of custom options and passed options in function definition

Tags: functions, options, optional-arguments

Why do these codes do not work?

```
Clear[fu]
Options[fu] = {"My Option" -> True};
fu[n_, opts : OptionsPattern[{Graph, fu}]] := (Print[
   OptionValue["My Option"]]; Graph[{n -> n + 1}, opts])

fu[1, VertexLabels -> Automatic, "My Option" -> False]
fu[1, "My Option" -> False, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

---

```
Clear[fu]
Options[fu] = {"My Option" -> True};
fu[n_, opts : OptionsPattern[Graph], 
  myopts : OptionsPattern[fu]] := (Print[OptionValue["My Option"]]; 
  Graph[{n -> n + 1}, opts])

fu[1, VertexLabels -> Automatic, "My Option" -> False]
fu[1, "My Option" -> False, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

No vertex labels and no print of `False`.

Also I want the options to be entered in any order, I do not understand why different output is produced when options are swapped?

Comment: Your first snippet needs a `FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graph]]` somewhere in there to work properly.

Comment: But then `fu[1, "My Option" -> False]` does not work, i.e. when you provide no `Graph` option at all.

Comment: "MyOption" is not an option for "Graph".  "Graph" takes only options: `Options[Graph]`

Comment: I had assumed you already knew about the two-arg form of `Graph[]`, which means that you need to do something like `Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graph]]` or `Splice[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graph]], Graph]` when doing the actual insertion of a (potentially empty) list of options.